# How to remove Unknown White Spaces in a vector?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have a vector with

```
temp <- c("hyndman_ensemble","four_theta","tbats")
```

when i print temp. there is unknown spaces in between four_theta and tbats (try this in your R console)

```
[1] "hyndman_ensemble" "four_theta"       "tbats"
```

I am using this temp in a legend. Due o which the legend has spaces and if there are 5 items in a list the data is missed.

Legend_function:

```
add_legend <- function(...) {
  opar <- par(fig=c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0),
              mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), new=TRUE)
  on.exit(par(opar))
  plot(0, 0, type='n', bty='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  legend(...)
}

cl <- rainbow(3) 
#Null plot just to display what is happening with the spaces in legend
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(0,100000))
add_legend("topright", legend=c("test1",temp), lty=1,
                   col=c("orange", cl),
                   horiz=TRUE, bty='n', cex=0.8)
```

This is how the plot is looking.
[image: plot result]

Even If I use trimws(), I get whitespaces (see image)

Can anyone tell me how to remove those spaces or any alternatives where I can print the legend outside the plot without any spaces(It is not mandatory for the legend to be on top)

[image: using trimws]

Comment: When you print to the console, there are no unknown spaces. See the double quotes? Those tell you the borders of the text elements. No spaces. The gaps in between the three vector values is not real whitespace. It is just how it chose to format the display into the console. So that is not the problem. The problem is somewhere else. (You can also do `cat(temp)` to see this)

Comment: @Adam, When u print temp. Dont you have double spaces? Because I tried the same line in 2 other devices. I see the space between four_theta and tbats

Comment: `trimws(temp, whitespace = '[\\h\\v]')
[1] "hyndman_ensemble" "four_theta"       "tbats"`, as @Adam says. That said, now what?

Comment: But trimws is still giving me white spaces @Chris

Comment: Check the updated image in the question @Chris

Comment: I have the same as you, just not as obvious on an around the corner comment. If you `legend=c('test1', c(temp[1], temp[2], temp[3]))`, does that have any useful effect?

Comment: sprintf('%s', temp), `[1] "hyndman_ensemble" "four_theta"       "tbats"`, and worse still swapped <- c('tbats', 'four_theta', 'hyndman_ensamble') `[1] "tbats"            "four_theta"       "hyndman_ensamble"`. I'll just follow now and wait for someone far smarter to opine as hard to see how 'something not there' propagates to plot.

Comment: legend=c('test1', c(temp[1], temp[2], temp[3])), Also gives same result. I am unable to figure out the problem here. Its weird

Comment: @Chris the default print method for a character vectors in the console allocates equal width in characters to each element. You can see this by entering `c("a", "b", "c", "d")` and then `c("aaa", "b", "c", "d")` and then `c("aaaaaaaaaa", "b", "c", "d")`. This is often nice because it helps things line up well when the vector is long enough to go on multiple lines. The `legend` function has similar behavior for the spacing it chooses. But changing one will not change the other--they just happen to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `text.width` parameter to "NA" the default is NULL:

```r
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(0,100000))
add_legend("topright", legend=temp, lty=1,
           col=c("orange", cl),
           horiz=TRUE, bty='n', cex=0.8, xjust= 0, text.width=NA)
```

[image]

How I understand it you have only one value with text.width = NULL, which corresponds to the width your longest entry would require. This is "hyndman_ensemble". If you set it to "NA" then you get a vector with 4 entries in this case. Each entry specifies the length each legend entry needs.

[image]
The source is here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html

Comment: text.width = NA is giving an error. 'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0

Comment: I had alook at the source code of the legend function and here (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/graphics/R/legend.R#L138) it shows what should be done when text.width is NA. Perhaps you need to update your R versions. You could also compare the output of `graphics::legend` (which prints the source code of the legend function you use) to the source code on github which is updated hourly.

Answer (score 3):

You could play with two arguments in your `add_legend` function. `text.width`:

> the width of the legend text in x ("user") coordinates. (Should be a
> single positive number even for a reversed x axis.) Defaults to the
> proper value computed by strwidth(legend).

And `x.intersp`:

> character interspacing factor for horizontal (x) spacing.

When running your code:

```
temp <- c("hyndman_ensemble","four_theta","tbats")

add_legend <- function(...) {
  opar <- par(fig=c(0, 1, 0, 1), oma=c(0, 0, 0, 0),
              mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0), new=TRUE)
  on.exit(par(opar))
  plot(0, 0, type='n', bty='n', xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
  legend(...)
}

cl <- rainbow(3) 
#Null plot just to display what is happening with the spaces in legend
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(0,100000))
add_legend("topright", legend=c("test1",temp), lty=1,
           col=c("orange", cl),
           horiz=TRUE, bty='n', cex=0.8)
```

Output with **Zoom** in Rstudio:

[image]

When try some values for `text.width` and `x.intersp` like this:

```
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(0,100000))
add_legend("topright", legend=c("test1",temp), lty=1,
           col=c("orange", cl),
           horiz=TRUE, bty='n', cex=0.8,
           x.intersp = 0.25,
           text.width = 0.3)
```

Results in the following output with **Zoom**:

[image]

As you can see it now also shows the "test1" of your function. You can play with the arguments to whatever you want.

Comment: Dang, bountied and everything...this should be the `reputable source` and answer. Mention might be made of where one might find `x.intersp` and `text.width` help for interested readers.

Comment: @Quinten. thank you. But I actually have 6 values in the temp. Due to the white spaces the legend is lost to the left side. Even if I put **pch=20** instead of lty. One value in legend is getting lost when I plot because of the spaces. if I try the same function with temp=c("test1","test2","test3","test4","test5") without using x.intersp and text.width, the legend is fine.(all the values can be seen)

Comment: Hi @bella_pa, did you trial and error with the values of x.intersp and text.width? Because with 6 values it is a different situation.

Comment: @Quinten Yes I did trail and error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally run your very nice `add_legend` function and `plot(NULL` and all values (test1 : tbats) are nicely arranged across top of plot, cl'd and all, so I can't replicate your issue. `plot(NULL,` was frankly an 'Ah Ha' for me. So often we are asking for 'data' to be employed with some suspect function, but `plot(NULL,` made this unnecessary and put focus on `par` attributes, as `temp` was sufficient data. And now I will attempt to post the plot below:

[image: plots all parameters]

```
R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)"
```

All of which is perhaps disappointing, and just post as an answer to include a plot picture.

And then again, actually using a total of 'five' items in legend, as suggested above:

```
temp2 <- c('hyndman_ensamble','four_theta','tbats','test2')

plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(0,100000))
add_legend("topright", legend=c("test1",temp2), lty=1,
                   col=c("orange", cl),
                   horiz=TRUE, bty='n', cex=0.8)
```

[image: five_items_legend]

And I drift in your direction...by losing 'test1' on left. And now to dive into `par(`, or perhaps `legend(`. With either `top` or `topleft` all items show (albeit tiny). So in this instance, without usefully suggested changes above by @quinten, `topright` is your problem.